# adding new dependecy in android leads to error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dependencies

I am adding https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker as a dependency for my project in the android studio which requires minsdkversion 16 or above.
increasing the minsdkversion leads to aapt2 error. can anyone let me know if there is any workaround here

Comment: share your log .

Comment: what is the error?